# Failed to convert the type of a missing '..' value to float type

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I need to convert all the values inside a column to type float. However, the column contains missing values which show up like this:

[image]

I used the following code to convert all the values to type float.

`df['col'].apply(lambda x : float(x) if x!=".." else np.nan)`

But got an error message telling:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

I would appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: `..` appears to just be the way a value of `None` is *rendered* in the string representation of the column, not the actual value stored in the column. The error message tells you what value of `x` is actually used.

Comment: Why not handle missing value before before conversion ? This will ensure you have the sale datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Editing and summing up

This wasn't clear from your input picture (please post as text) but it appears your input dataframe in fact contains both *None* and *'..'*

- error *"TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'"* indicates presence of 'None'
- error *ValueError: could not convert string to float: '..'* now indicates presence of some actual '..' strings.
- Forget applying lambdas: [pandas.DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) knows to skip NoneType without raising an error. Just get rid of arbitrary strings like '..' first.

#### Adapted answer:

**One-liner, for in-place conversion:**

```
df['col'] = np.where(df['col']=='..', None, 
                                      df['col']).astype('float')
```

**Alternatively, decomposing steps simplifies the syntax:** (no need for [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html))

(0) *A mock-up of your initial dataframe: (Please post as text instead of image)*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['-0.123',None, '..']})
df
      col
0  -0.123
1    None 
2    '..'
```

(1) First, curate your data by replacing cells of value '..' with *None*:

```
df.loc[df['col']=='..'] = None
df
      col
0  -0.123
1    None
2    None
```

(2) Then apply data type conversion:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('float64')
df
      col
0  -0.123
1     NaN
2     NaN
```

Missing data are converted to 'not a number'.
Resulting data type is as requested:

```
df.dtypes
col    float64
dtype: object
```

To go further: More pandas built-in [column-wise datatype converters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15891038/12846804) to be used instead of crafting lambda functions.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code, and again got the same error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '..' . Are there any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your data is actually None, to skip them just check if they're None.

I guess this will do your job

```py
df['col'].apply(lambda x : float(x) if x is not None and x != '..' else np.nan)
```

---

Or alternatively you can use this:

```py
def convert(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan


df['col'].apply(convert)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code and got the following error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '..'

Comment: Then chack for both :) I edited my answer